# Text Input Character Limits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I'm pulling a string back from the database via jQuery, into a textarea, then upon user approval, grabbing that value and placing it in a text input.

Right now, my code looks roughly like this (some omitted of course):

```
var string = $('#textarea').val(); // Contains 145,095 char string

console.log(string.length); // logs 145,095 characters

// Clear Input and add approved string
$('#input').val('').val(string); // Contains 14,023 char string
```

Wondering where those ~131,000 characters are going? Based on some initial research, my understanding is that Chrome (in this case) should support millions of characters in a text input, so is this a jQuery limitation? I haven't found anything to support that hunch. Suggested work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to clear the input and then add the new value in, the JS can be streamlined to this:

```
$('#input').val(string); // Contains 14,023 char string
```

To be sure the value is being truncated, can you try and do a truthy match like so:

```
if (string === $('#input').val()) {
    console.log('the values match');
}
```

If it does return true then it is just a visual thing, the content of the input box is intact :-) If not, then I would suggest adding a maxlength attribute to the input.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're right, the values matched and submitting the form carried through the correct string. But copy and pasting the string into a text editor carries through the *incorrect* data. Fascinating. And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

probably it is jQuery limitation

try to put Your text by parts or

try to use clear js : `document.getElementById('input').value = string;`